# Installing secondary hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive

I wanted to install secondary hard drive so I mounted the hard drive in the computer and I connected the power cable and the data cable. I powered up the computer and chose the master hard drive in the boot menu  (the secondary drive appeared as well). The OS (windows 10 pro) was started but the OS didn't show the secondary hard drive.

How can I install the secondary hard drive corrently?

**Edit:** The hard drive doesn't appeared on the "disc management" tool but it **does** appear on the BIOS menu.

[image: This is the "disk managment" tool]

I am very sorry about my computer languege. you have to belive me that this is the disk management tool.....

Comment: have you tried to see if you can locate it in the disk management utility?

Comment: You have to intilaize the HDD.  In order to intialize the HDD you have to assigned it a file system.

Comment: Take screen shot of your diskmgmt and share here.

Comment: See if Device Manager tells any problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't really make clear what kind of HDD you are using. Is this an IDE or a SATA drive?

Problems like these can appear when the cables are broken. Try changing both the SATA port you plug the cable in and the cable itself if possible. Another possibility is that you use the SATA ports of an extra chip which is disabled in the BIOS/UEFI.

Also, what kind of motherboard are you using? Try installing its chipset/SATA drivers.

Go to 'device manager' and search for any exclamation marks or anything like that, which could signify a problem with drivers or devices.

For your screenshots you should consider changing your system's language, you are able to use and understand english, so that shouldn't pose a problem for you.